# Using SG Component (SearchView) Possible to observed gridview in MainScene?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I checked the grid view in SearchView. It's a child of the layout. But, Is it possible to observe the grid view inside of the main scene like It's available or not? I checked both fields (rowItemFocused, rowItemSelected), It's displayed always. When the grid view is visible or not.

I print Searchview It's like below :

```
m.searchView : <Component: roSGNode:SearchView> =
{
    childRenderOrder: "last"
    clippingRect: <Component: roAssociativeArray>
    enableRenderTracking: false
    inheritParentOpacity: true
    inheritParentTransform: true
    muteAudioGuide: false
    opacity: 1
    renderPass: 0
    renderTracking: "disabled"
    rotation: 0
    scale: <Component: roArray>
    scaleRotateCenter: <Component: roArray>
    translation: <Component: roArray>
    visible: true
    change: <Component: roAssociativeArray>
    focusable: false
    focusedChild: <Component: roSGNode:Group>
    id: ""
    close: false
    content: <Component: roInvalid>
    errorCode: 0
    errorMsg: ""
    hintText: "Search here for moviename/releasedate"
    noResultsLabelText: "No results"
    overhang: <Component: roSGNode:Overhang>
    posterShape: "16x9"
    query: ""
    rowItemFocused: <Component: roArray>
    rowItemSelected: <Component: roArray>
    rowPosterShapes: <Component: roArray>
    saveState: false
    showNoResultsLabel: true
    showSpinner: false
    style: ""
    theme: <Component: roAssociativeArray>
    updateTheme: invalid
    viewContentGroup: <Component: roSGNode:Group>
    wasClosed: false
    wasShown: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your `m.searchView` is already referenced from the main scene you can do this:

```
m.searchView.observeField("focusedChild", "onSearchViewFocusChange")
...
sub onSearchViewFocusChange()
  if m.searchView.isInFocusChain() =  true
    ' searchview has focus
  else
    ' searchView lost focus
  end if
end sub
```

If `m.searchView` is not yet referenced from the main scene, you can find a way to pass the reference when it's created.  (From your question I'm not able to determine this architecture)

Hope this may help